# Samsung SSD: Hardware encryption and speed

Tags: ssd, encryption, self-encrypting-drive, tcg-opal

I'm concerned about speed changes of the Samsung MZ-M5E1T0BW [850-EVO](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-M5E1T0BW) when hardware encryption/decryption is enabled. I can't find any information in the data sheets. Do you guys know if there is a (significant) loss of read/write speed when the hardware encryption is enabled? Thanks!

Comment: There should be no difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But why do you think there will be no performance loss?

Comment: I simply will respond, why do you believe there would be, you asked if would be any and there won't be which is the entire purpose of the hardware doing the encryption.

Comment: But just because the hardware does the encryption doesn't mean the encryption/decryption process can handle the read/write speed of the ssd. That's why I'm asking...

Comment: I will say it another way.  If using this feature effective performance people wouldn't use it.  I will repeat, using the hardware encryption feature of this device, will not have minimal effect on its performance in terms of speed.

Comment: Okay. But from where do you have this information? Or is it just a guess?

Comment: It is based on my vast amounts of experiences.  It is not a guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The performance drop with Samsung Self Encryption Drive (SED) is quite small.  This review reports SED offers twice the speed of software encryption in this test.

```
                  SSD no encryption    SED
Large Data Read   178.00               169.33
Large Data Write  170.80               164.50
```

http://www.thessdreview.com/daily-news/latest-buzz/storage-visions-2014-update/