# Zero filling (vs one-filling) drives: convention or practical reason?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, format, overwrite, physical-wear

Many tutorials suggest zero-filling a drive to fully erase it for further use, but I have never seen anyone suggest one-filling a drive for any reason. Is this an arbitrary convention, or is there a reason why zero-filling is better than one-filling?

Is one harder on the device physically than the other? Other than security (for which I understand a random fill is better), are there any other possible considerations?

Comment: Some discussion over here....https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/why-is-writing-zeros-or-random-data-over-a-hard-drive-multiple-times-better-th

Comment: Thanks, I did find that but it is a slightly different question and is focused on data security. Regarding that question, I would ask whether multiple writes of all ones are functionally identical to multiple writes of all zeros.

Comment: Yeah but there was some useful information on how a magnetic drive stores a 1 or a 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is one harder on the device physically than the other?

Nowadays many drives [internally encrypt data](https://superuser.com/q/986387/432690), so all zeros (or all ones) are stored internally as "mixed" values anyway. Therefore it shouldn't matter. In case of flash memory (like SSD) use TRIM to "fully erase it for further use" (zero-filling or one-filling is [not equivalent to TRIM](https://superuser.com/q/1242000/432690)).

> are there any other possible considerations?

I'm a Linux user. From my point of view zeros are extremely easy to get because there is `/dev/zero` in the OS. Getting all ones is not that easy. It's the only reason to prefer zeros I can think of. And since the easiest way to fill a drive with *anything* is to use `dd`, `cat` or `cp` (rather than writing your own program), filling with zeros from `/dev/zero` seems natural.

Zero-filling is easy:

```
cp /dev/zero /dev/sdX
```

while one-filling requires some additional work:

```
</dev/zero tr '\0' '\377' >/dev/sdX
```

Note the latter can be used to fill the device with any fixed byte value. In this sense all ones are as "hard" to get as any other byte except all zeros.