# Why is this data seemingly gone?

Tags: windows, ssd, data-recovery, file-recovery, recovery

This question is a bit long, but people often prefer to have all the details instead of being required to ask for them, so I've included as much detail as possible.

I received a frantic call from a friend who had just accidentally deleted their `Desktop` folder in Windows using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

Apparently, they only perform backups once a week *(not often enough, IMO)*, and had an entire week's worth of work in that folder on their SSD.

Their `Desktop` folder was on a data-only NTFS partition, and no applications besides a file manager were open at the time.  Their machine uses Windows 7.

They already had `Recuva` and `Wise Data Recovery` installed on a different partition, and had an additional third NTFS formatted partition with many GBs of empty space.

They didn't have any other drives available.

I recommended that they do absolutely nothing except run `Recuva` right away to undelete (recover) all folders and files from the partition that had the `Desktop` folder, and send the output to that third (mostly empty) partition.  It turns out that `Recuva` has a serious bug that prevents recovery when the `Desktop` folder has been deleted, so they were not able to attempt an immediate recovery.

About 15 minutes had now elapsed since they deleted the `Desktop` folder.  Their computer remained on during that entire time.

Given the lack of a successful recovery with `Recuva`, I then recommended that they do absolutely nothing except now run `Wise Data Recovery` to try to recover all possible folders and files from the partition that had the `Desktop` folder and restore them to that third (mostly empty) partition.

Well, it turns out `Wise Data Recovery` also has a bit of problem when the `Desktop` folder has been deleted.  It took me about 5 minutes to figure out a workaround over the phone, and they were able to perform what looked like a full recovery using that tool.

Unfortunately 99% of the recovered files contain nothing but nulls.

I then recommended they perform a "deep scan" with `Wise Data Recovery`.  After about half an hour, `Wise Data Recovery` completed its deep scan.  My friend then performed the recovery again, but the results were no better.

There was much cussing on the other end of the line, and my friend's stress was palpable.

I had them try `Recuva` again, but that previously mentioned bug with `Recuva` is pretty nasty.  It took me about 15 minutes to figure out a workaround for that bug, and then my friend was able to use `Recuva` to undelete the `Desktop` folder and all its subfolders and files (onto that third partition).

Unfortunately, again, almost every recovered file consisted of nothing but nulls.

I was a little surprised that neither tool could successfully recover the data.  I was surprised because:

1. Very little time had elapsed since the deletion (thus if TRIM was enabled, it may not have had much to reallocate).
2. The computer was ***not*** turned off, placed in hibernation, placed in standby, nor was the user ever logged off.
3. My friend describes that machine as "lean and mean" with all extraneous Windows services disabled.
4. Shadow service was disabled on the data partition and the third partition.
5. No data at all should have been written to the partition that had the `Desktop` folder by any applications.
6. Besides the file manager, no applications were running.
7. None of the partitions were encrypted by the OS or any third-party software tools (though true, Journeyman Geek has pointed out the following may be relevant: [Why does my SSD internally encrypt data, even without a password set?](https://superuser.com/questions/986387/why-does-my-ssd-internally-encrypt-data-even-without-a-password-set/986392)).
8. All restored data was written to a separate partition (albeit, on an SSD, I'm not sure how much that helps).

For over 1.25GB of deleted work, only about 80KB was recovered.

Question: Given such a short period of time since the deletion, and the lack of activity on the computer, why would those recovery tools mostly only find data blocks filled with nulls?

BTW, this question is long, and I appreciate you reading it.  As of this writing, my friend's computer is still turned on and not being used.  Ideas for recovery are welcome; if a new question is appropriate for that, please just ask, and I can post an edited copy of this question, with the focus on that topic.

Comment: Its been years since I did forensics but I was told (and read some papers long forgotten) that SSDs had some quirks. Modern ones do things like encrypting or scrambling  the drive - which... improves reliability, and I read entirely contradictory papers on SSD recovery.

Comment: Recovery from an SSD, as you can imagine is an entirely different beast.  You can't just scan every sector and look for fragments, and use algorithms, to patch together files.  SSDs constantly mark new and old seectors available while making other sectors unavailable.  There really isn't a good solution to this problem.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I was hoping you might reply. Thanks. I forgot to mention that the drive was not encrypted by the OS (I'll make an edit to the Q) or *intentionally* hardware encrypted by the drive. I still don't consider myself an SSD expert (ya, I know, it's 2022), but the "scrambling" you mentioned (combined with Ramhound's comment) does make sense as a loose approximation of the implementation of current SSD technology.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks so much for taking the time to read the Q and reply.  I'm glad you did.  I think your last sentence, although sad, may sum it up: *"There really isn't a good solution to this problem"*.  If so, that's a big downside to SSDs.  Your comment implies that you can't even just scan every sector looking for specific strings.  Am I understanding you correctly on that?

Comment: I have an old post covering this https://superuser.com/questions/986387/why-does-my-ssd-internally-encrypt-data-even-without-a-password-set/986392#986392 Not sure how much help it will be

Comment: Another good reason to Not use a SSD for data storage

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks.  I'll check out that QA.

Comment: @Moab Is your recommendation HDDs in a RAID configuration?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - RAID brings its own challenges. I oversimplified SSDs by the way. File recovery on a 20 TB mechanical HDD is difficult too

Comment: @Ramhound With RAID striping, definitely, but is that true with RAID mirroring as well?  I can ask a separate Q, if you prefer.

Comment: tbh, the performance improvements of SSDs are so much that it feels like a waste. I think most modern cloud backups are realtime and backing up the desktop and docs makes a ton of sense. Data recovery generally is a last resort of people who are too <something> to back up :D. And don't forget HDDs can catastrophically fail, I got some fun ones in the past

Answer (score 5):

> Very little time had elapsed since the deletion (thus if TRIM was enabled, it may not have had much to reallocate).

Time elapsed is irrelevant, for two reasons:

1. By default, NTFS issues discards (TRIM commands) synchronously as soon as a file is deleted or truncated – you don't have to wait for the weekly "Optimize" task for it to happen.

   (You can feel this when deleting thousands of files and seeing the SSD at 100% – probably 99% of that time is spent in processing the TRIM commands, and disabling the synchronous discard through fsutil makes file removal go really fast.)
2. Probably the majority of SSDs implement the "Read zero after TRIM" behavior, where they don't merely mark the trimmed sectors "available", but *immediately* unmap them (and possibly physically erase the flash storage) during the TRIM command.

   After being discarded, those sectors no longer correspond to any physical flash storage (until written to again) and reading from them will cause the SSD's firmware to just immediately return zeros.

Honestly, losing a week's worth of work is still an improvement over losing 10 years' worth of work.

> All restored data was written to a separate partition (albeit, on an SSD, I'm not sure how much that helps).

It would only have helped if the sectors with data *hadn't* been discarded using TRIM (or at least if "Read zero after TRIM" wasn't the standard behavior).

It's still the job of an SSD to maintain a consistent view of what data was written to what sectors, like any other storage medium would. So if partition 1 has some sectors that contain some data (e.g. your deleted files), those sectors will always continue to have that data until the OS writes something else; writing to partition 2 will never destroy data that's still being held by partition 1.

With TRIM it's different – the SSD considers the corresponding flash areas "available for re-use" after the sectors were trimmed and it's *technically* true that recovering to partition 2 may still overwrite flash areas that previously belonged to partition 1. But this only makes a difference if a specialist tries to recover data directly from the flash storage – those sectors already became inaccessible to the OS (and therefore, inaccessible to software-based recovery tools) as soon as discards were issued to them, and there is no SSD command to map the sectors back, so as far as software tools can see the data is already gone the moment TRIM was issued.

> None of the partitions were encrypted by the OS or any third-party software tools (though true, Journeyman Geek has pointed out the following may be relevant: Why does my SSD internally encrypt data, even without a password set?).

The encryption done internally by the SSD is only relevant if you (or a recovery specialist) intend to physically open the SSD and read data out of the flash chips, bypassing the SSD's controller.

Otherwise, as long as the data is being read through the SSD's normal interface (i.e. using the standard NVMe or SATA commands), the SSD will transparently decrypt any data that's being read – after all, the whole idea is that the OS *doesn't* need to be aware of encryption happening – and your software-based recovery tools will be seeing exactly the same data as the OS is seeing.

Comment: Oh wow, I received responses from Journeyman Geek, then Ramhound, then user1686... the trifecta of top-notch Super User gurus, IMO.  I sincerely feel much gratitude to you all.  Your answer is very helpful and your second point reminds me of something I read, but wasn't on the top of my mind... that modern SSDs often implement "Read zero after TRIM".  I forgot about that, and the results my friend experienced indicate that this could be the case.

Comment: I feel really sad for my friend (they are literally in tears).  They just realized that they were backing up absolutely everything *besides* their `Desktop` folder every week, but that particular folder was not included in backups due to a UI issue in their backup tool (they thought it was being backed up, but it was not).  So it turns out they lost nearly 2 years of work on many important documents.  They said they have probably lost 500-1000 hours of work that was yet to be published.

Comment: I just thought of something... why would *almost all* the data be gone, but not *all* the data?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - minimum sector size. I got doubts 500 KB is anything but a text document. Even your basic Word document is larger than 500 KB

Comment: My only guess is that the recovery tool might have scraped them out of the MFT. "About 500 kB recovered" sounds like it consists mostly of very small files – on NTFS filesystems, when a file is below ~1kB (not sure of the actual limit), it can actually be stored ["resident"](https://superuser.com/questions/1185461/maximum-size-of-file-that-can-be-stored-entirely-in-ntfs-master-file-table-mft) within the MFT, without having a separate data allocation.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll ask, but that sounds likely.  They mentioned "mostly just some tiny text files and icons" were recovered, so I'm guessing they were all <1KB.  I'll find out.

Comment: I think you are likely *spot on* regarding the recovered files being stored directly in the MFT.  It turns out that all the files recovered were under 600 bytes, which seems to match https://superuser.com/questions/1185461/maximum-size-of-file-that-can-be-stored-entirely-in-ntfs-master-file-table-mft (notably, though, no files over 600 bytes were recovered, even though there were apparently around 100 of them that were >650 bytes, but <1KB).

Comment: Excellent answer. Finally someone who gets TRIM right.

Comment: For completeness sake: If data is really important but lost due to TRIM then disconnect drive from power ASAP and send to a data recovery lab. Data may still be recoverable as long as blocks weren't actually erased by garbage collector. But even if it is it's not uncommon several (stale) copies of the data can be found as data is frequently copied by the firmware in order to consolidate blocks to be trimmed.