Check if file referenced in MFT actually exists on NTFS volume
I have a large NTFS disk. Due to unwise modification of partitions (namely, I enlarged C at the expense of D), I now have a lot of files that appear in windows explorer but cannot be open. I suspect the reason is that the partition process did move the partition boundary but did not touch the MFT, such that some files are referenced in the MFT (of D) but the address there actually points to nothing at all (presumably to a portion of the disk that now belongs to C).
So every now and again, trying to open a random file results in a "file cannot open error" (the exact error depends on the application trying to open it).
I have backups so this is a nuisance more than a crisis. But it would be good to be able to identify all the affected files, and replace them by their backup'd version once and for all.
Is there a way to batch check all the files and see which one actually exists ?
EDIT: after comments. Apparently my interpretation is incorrect. Further investigation reveals that the offending files exist, but contain only NULL. Therefore, although I don't know how the situation actually arose, the problem can be rephrased as "identify files which content is purely NULL".
There is a possible solution there How to quickly determine which files contain only NULLs so they can be safely deleted (Windows)? , but of course alternatives do not harm...

That doesn't sound like a plausible explanation, as the addresses used are relative to start of partition (i.e. start of filesystem), not to start of the whole disk – and also, MFT entries are what makes a file "exist". Unless the NTFS-resizing tool really screwed things up... What kind of errors do you get?

Thanks for the analysis. As I said the actual message is application specific. XNView says, for instance "File cannot be loaded" while opening a png. Looking at the file with an Hex editor, the content in only NULL (820712 instances of NULL in that case). Okular says "unable to open file XX". Ditto, it's full of NULL. With Office I have "powerpoint detected a problem in file XXX, powerpoint can try to repair it". The common factor is that all the corrupt files contain only NULL, a number of NULL's corresponding to their size.

Right, so they do exist in every sense at the filesystem level, except for not having valid data... and NTFS has no way of knowing whether the data is valid or not. (It has no data checksums the way zfs/btrfs/ReFS might.) That makes it a rather different problem than if you had a filesystem-level error showing up – it means you need to search for "all-NUL" files, rather than "impossible to open" files.

Good rephrasing. So the question stands - how to ?

Ah-ha !   https://superuser.com/questions/1749601/how-to-quickly-determine-which-files-contain-only-nulls-so-they-can-be-safely-de  Still interested in other options...

Unless diskpart really screwed up, which isn't likely, it doesn't seem like the issue is related to the resize - has chkdsk <DriveLetter>: /OfflineScanAndFix been run against D: and C:? Boot to WinRE Command Prompt to run against C: so you see the output (Shutdown /f /r /o /t 0 → Once booted to WinRE: Advanced → Troubleshoot → Command Prompt), with time varying depending on the size of C: - max C: partition size required would be no more than 300GB (200GB more than enough for most) if user data is configured to store on a partition other than C: (always recommended),
